# Issue with SSH on RHEL while monitoring logs from SpectorSoft Server Manager

Tags: linux, ssh, logging, monitoring

I have 3 servers running RHEL hosting a number of Java applications where each of them generates a log file which I am monitoring from a Windows-based machine with the use of SpectorSoft Server Manager. The idea is to match a specific pattern or string found in these logs and send a relevant email.

For some reason, most of the time I get service disruption, because in the logs of SpectorSoft Server Manager, I get the following error,

"No suitable authentication method found to complete authentication."

Even though it works as expected for some time, the error is quite frequent and causes many issues as the logs keep generating but the alerts are not triggered when they should. Sometimes, I have also noticed that when this error happens, I cannot even connect via SSH or WinSCP to these servers.

Any ideas what might be causing this issue?

Please find below the SSH logs (/var/log/secure) as well from one of the RHEL machines.

Jun  3 08:11:15 machine_hostname sshd[10921]: Accepted password for root from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 61345 ssh2

Jun  3 08:11:15 machine_hostname sshd[10921]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)

Jun  3 08:11:15 machine_hostname sshd[10921]: subsystem request for sftp

Jun  3 08:11:15 machine_hostname sshd[10921]: Received disconnect from 
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: 11: Connection terminated by the client.

Jun  3 08:11:15 machine_hostname sshd[10921]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Roughly how frequent is frequent? You want to 1st slice the problem in 2: is it on the linux side or the windows side? Are the failed SSH/WinSCP attempts from the same windows machine that runs SpectorSoft? How about SSH attempts using some other (preferably linux) machine?

Comment: Thank you for your help. We managed to get it sorted by reducing the interval of polling the logs from SpectorSoft, basically from 1 minute to 30 seconds. This somehow solved the issue which I think it might be related with the SSH session timeout...